# Capturing time taken by sub components in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I am working on tuning a stored procedure. It is a huge stored proc and joins tables that has about 6-7 million records.

My question is how do I determine the time spent in the components of the proc. The proc has 1 big select with many temp tables created on the fly (read sub-queries).

I tried using SET STATISTICS TIME ON, SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON.

I am looking to isolate a chunk of code that takes the most time and not sure of how to do it.

Please help.

PS: I did try to google it, searched on Stackoverflow..........No luck. Here is one question that I looked at 
[How to improve SQL Server query containing nested sub query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199932/how-to-improve-sql-server-query-containing-nested-sub-query)

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try out SQL Sentry's SQL Plan Explorer.  It gives you visual help in finding the problem.  It is also a free tool.  It highlights the bits that cost a lot of I/O or CPU, versus a generic percent.

Here's where you can check it out:
http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp

Eric

Comment: +1 from me too. Looks a promising tool. Will explore further.

Comment: Incidentally, if you get the actual plan, you can get the actual rows affected, etc.  THat is more handy than just an estimated plan.  You can do this in SSMS by hitting <ctrl> + M before running.

Comment: @Yogendra - bear in mind it will not show you time spent per operator, just a cost

Comment: Also be aware actual exec plans can slow performance of the query :)

Comment: @JNK totally agree.  Bottom line is that the info usually pays for itself and getting actual rows, etc. from the actual plan yields a better probability of success. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I realize your asking for "time" (the how long), but maybe you should focus on the "what".  What I mean is, tuning to the results of Execution Plan.  Ideally using the "Show Execution Plan" is going to give you the biggest bang.  And it will tell you, via percentages where it is cost the most resources.
If you are in SSMS 2008 you can right click in your query window and click "Include Execution Plan".

Comment: **This is very wrong.** The percentages are based on estimates, not actuals, and  they **DO NOT HAVE A TIME COMPONENT**.  They are based on IO/CPU/Memory but not based on time spent at all.   The most expensive operator could in fact be the fastest.

Comment: I updated it from time to "cost" for better clarification.  But I think your missing the point of my Answer.  The questioner was asking for time.  Time of queries is not the ideal tuning metric.  Utilizing the Actual Execution Plan will provide the insight this person is looking for.

Also, please explain, "The most expensive operator could in fact be the fastest."  Relative to the plan itself?  In any execution plan, there is going to be a "most expensive operator."

Comment: If he is most worried about time spent on the query, then time IS the most relevant measure.  We don't know what his scenario is.  There could be no concurrency and it could be a post-ETL build operation where he has the server to himself.

Comment: Yes, the most expensive operator can be (and often is) the one that executes the fastest within a plan.  If there is high memory/cpu but low IO the "cost" will be high but it can execute very quickly.

Comment: Time spent on the query can be variable from each execution depending on system resources. That's why tuning to the execution plan will provide the most insight. I work in healthcare where our databases are mission critical. Resources are variable. The SAN I/O may be free and clear one second, but saturated the next from another system. Using time-based metrics will not lead you down the correct path. Even with SQL's Time Statistics, each query could yield wildly variable results, due to access to system resources. If you look at the execution plan it will tell you where to begin optimizing.

Comment: As I said, it depends on the scenario.  As a rule, the operator that takes the most time will always take the most time, but the amount of time it takes will vary.  It will be relatively consistent percentage wise until you start hitting multiple drives with very different loads.  I still disagree with your methodology.

Comment: @JNK, You disagree with my methodology (Use the Execution Plan) and down vote me, but you comment "+1 - That's a great tool. – JNK" when someone recommends a tool... To look at the Execution Plan?

Comment: it's  a different view of the exec plan that fills in a lot of holes left by the one in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

In  your scenario, the best way to do this is to just run the components individually.  Bear in mind the below is relevant for tuning for execution time primarily (in a low-contingency/concurrency environment).  You may have other priorities under a heavy concurrent load.

I have to do a very similar break down on a regular basis for different procedures I have to tune.  As a rule the general methodology I follow is:

1 - Do a baseline run

2 - Add `PRINT` or `RAISERROR` commands between portions that return the current time to aid in identifying which steps take the longest.

3 - Break down the queries individually.  I normally run portions on their own (omit `JOIN` conditions) to see what the variance is.  If it is a very long-running query you can add a `TOP` clause to any `SELECT`s to limit the returns.  As long as you are consistent this will still give you a good idea.

4 - Tweak the components from step 3 that take the most time.  If you have complicated subqueries, maybe make them indexed `#temp` tables to see if that helps.  `CTE`s as a rule never help performance, so you may need to materialize those as well.